# why consumer doesn't consume from all the partition

Tags: apache-kafka

Cluster set up: Kafka -0.8.2 version
3 kafka and 3 zookeeper servers.

consumer configuration:

```
zookeeper.connect:localhost:2181,localhost:2181,localhost:2181
group.id:testerGroup
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms:6000
zookeeper.sync.time.ms:200
auto.commit.interval.ms:1000
```

Topic : topic1 
I am running the High level consumer through java code. My topic has 2 partition(0 and 1).
I produced 1000 data, partition 0 holds 500 data and partition 1 holds 500 data. I received only partition 0 data and I am not receiving partition 1 data.

while checking with kafka offset monitor, partion 1 data are considered as lag.

why the partion 1 data is considered as lag and partion 0 provides the data.

Comment: I'm not sure it's your root problem, but is there a reason that you are connecting to localhost:2181 three times?

Comment: Posting your code on how you chose to consume the data would be helpful as well